# jQuery: can't find the element on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am encountering a strange Javascript behavior:

**index.html**

```
<div id="content">
    <button type="button" onclick="goDownload()">Click</button>
</div>
```

**hello.html**

```
<div id="myId">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        doStuff();
    });
</script>
```

**file.js**

```
function goDownload() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "hello.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#content").append(response);
        }
    });        
}

function doStuff() {
    //If I wait a little bit (e.g alert/timer), the below works
    //otherwise it does not

    $("#myId").html("Hello from doStuff()");
}
```

I know the ajax call is a async request, but I cannot see at what point this is becoming an issue. (I know I can do my doStuff() in success callback, but this is not the case for me). Any ideas?

Comment: What is the strange behavior?

Comment: Any specific reason why doStuff cannot be called from your success callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of an `$.ajax` call is a Deferred object ( http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/ ), so you can take advantage of its methods to detect when it's done:

```
var downloadWaiting;

function goDownload() {
    downloadWaiting = $.ajax({
        url: "hello.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $("#content").append(response);
        }
    });
}

function doStuff() {
    downloadWaiting.done(function () {
        $("#myId").html("Hello from doStuff()");
    });
}
```